# Error installing OpenCV Java for Mac (with Homebrew)

Tags: java, macos, opencv, cmake, homebrew

I am trying to install OpenCV Java for Mac with homebrew, but CMake is giving me error during the process. The steps I have taken are as follows:

1. Installing CMake
2. Installing ant with: `brew install ant`
3. Changing the variable `-DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF` to `ON`
4. Installing OpenCV using: `brew install --build-from-source opencv`

Here is what gets printed to my terminal (error below):

```
==> Downloading https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.2.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/gtalmor/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/2606bd5bbd9d3231837dd3bc1f76c1a935cb4ce0eae9c2a472fd15c77dfbb510--opencv-4.2.0.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/4.2.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/gtalmor/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/47ad25f9dd163b753420e122bad3928281696bdb5cd1c925fc90cf82e91ccda5--opencv_contrib-4.2.0.tar.gz
==> cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG


==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/gtalmor/Library/Logs/Homebrew/opencv/02.make:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../lib/liblibprotobuf.a(gzip_stream.cc.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib ../lib/liblibprotobuf.a
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../lib/liblibprotobuf.a(arenastring.cc.o) has no symbols
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../lib/liblibprotobuf.a(io_win32.cc.o) has no symbols
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../lib/liblibprotobuf.a(gzip_stream.cc.o) has no symbols
[ 26%] Built target libprotobuf
[ 26%] Linking CXX static library ../../../../../../lib/libmultiview.a
cd /tmp/opencv-20200203-6856-92bpyc/opencv-4.2.0/build/modules/sfm/src/libmv/libmv/multiview && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.16.3/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/multiview.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /tmp/opencv-20200203-6856-92bpyc/opencv-4.2.0/build/modules/sfm/src/libmv/libmv/multiview && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.16.3/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/multiview.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ar qc ../../../../../../lib/libmultiview.a  CMakeFiles/multiview.dir/conditioning.cc.o CMakeFiles/multiview.dir/euclidean_resection.cc.o CMakeFiles/multiview.dir/fundamental.cc.o CMakeFiles/multiview.dir/fundamental_kernel.cc.o CMakeFiles/multiview.dir/homography.cc.o CMakeFiles/multiview.dir/panography.cc.o CMakeFiles/multiview.dir/panography_kernel.cc.o CMakeFiles/multiview.dir/projection.cc.o CMakeFiles/multiview.dir/robust_estimation.cc.o CMakeFiles/multiview.dir/robust_fundamental.cc.o CMakeFiles/multiview.dir/robust_resection.cc.o CMakeFiles/multiview.dir/triangulation.cc.o CMakeFiles/multiview.dir/twoviewtriangulation.cc.o
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../../../../../../lib/libmultiview.a(robust_estimation.cc.o) has no symbols
/usr/bin/ranlib ../../../../../../lib/libmultiview.a
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../../../../../../lib/libmultiview.a(robust_estimation.cc.o) has no symbols
[ 26%] Built target multiview
make: *** [all] Error 2

READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting
```

Any idea what went wrong? I have seen posts of people with same issue and exact same error in different forums, but no one seem to have resolved it..

Comment: I don't recommend changing the formula. If you want Java support, it's better to download OpenCV sources and build it by hand.